# How to make a event run immediately after a GUI program starts in wxpython?

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython

I'm working on a GUI program in which I already bind a start button with one event, and when I click the start button, the event runs as I like. My question is, if I want my program to start the event immediately after the GUI program starts, which means the start button is immediately being "clicked" once the program starts, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main frame constructor set a one-shot timer with interval 0 that fires the event.

Comment: Would you please be more specific? I just don't know where to put the code and how to add the timer.

Comment: @Shane: I'm not sure how I can be more specific. Here's some docs on wxPython timers: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Timer, Google for more. Do you have a main frame for your application? Does it have a constructor?

Answer (score 1):

In the `__init__`( ) for your main frame put this:

> wx.CallAfter( func_name )